# Put different kinds of user-controls in a wpf grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, grid

I'm starting with WPF, and I want to create a grid which shows shapes according to the context. So for example in one cell, I can have either a circle, or a rectangle !

I created my custom circle "Circle.Xaml" and my custom rectangle "Rectangle.Xaml". I created also their View-Models "CircleVM.Cs" and "RectangleVM.Cs".

Now, I added a listBox to my application to let the user to put either the circle, or the rectangle in my grid cell.

My problem is:

1. How can I bind all that with my cell ? In order to put the right control when I'll add simply his corresponding View-Model in the collection binded to my grid !!
2. How can I set the DataContext of a view when the view-Model constructor has arguments which are not defined at the initialisation (Values of arguments are according to the context too) !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a `DataTemplate` in a `Resources` section, you have a choice... you can provide it with a name and then use that name to reference it, or you leave it without a name.  If a `DataTemplate` has no name (or `x:Key` value) then  it will automatically be applied to all objects of the type specified in it unless they have another `DataTemplate` explicity set with a named `DataTemplate`.

Therefore, you can add the following into your application `Resources` section (in `App.xaml`) and it will apply to all of the view models in your application:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:CircleVM}">
    <Views:Circle />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:RectangleVM}">
    <Views:Rectangle />
</DataTemplate>
```

Please note that you will need to add the required XML Namespaces... something like this:

```
xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:YourApplicationName.FolderNameIfApplicable"
xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:YourApplicationName.FolderNameIfApplicable"
```

Now, whenever you add an instance of your `CircleVM` class into the UI, the related `Circle.xaml` file will be shown:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding YourViewModelProperty}" />
```

To switch between the two view models, create a property as above... again, you have two choices:

```
public object YourViewModelProperty // with valid getter/setter removed here
```

Or better, create a `BaseViewModel` class that implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged`interface and extend all of your view models from it:

```
public BaseViewModel YourViewModelProperty // with valid getter/setter removed here
```

The final step to take when the user changes their selection is to set the value of this property:

```
if (userHasChosenCircle) YourViewModelProperty = new CircleVM();
else YourViewModelProperty = new RectangleVM();
```